# next.js: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i trying to use react-countdown for my page and it worked although there are a few notes like `react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`
here my full code

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import React from "react"
import Countdown from "react-countdown"
import {Container, Button, Row, Col, Form, FormControl, InputGroup} from 'react-bootstrap'

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
  // Random component
  const Completionist = () => <span>You are good to go!</span>;

  const styleCol = {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'grey',
    fontSize: '82px',
    fontWeight: 600,
    display: 'grid',
    fontFamily: 'VERDANABOLD'
  }

  const styleColSpan = {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: '16px'
  }

  // Renderer callback with condition
  const renderer = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
    if (completed) {
      // Render a complete state
      return <Completionist />;
    } else {
      // Render a countdown
      return (
        <>
          <Col style={styleCol} className={style.clockFrame} lg={3} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>{days} <span style={styleColSpan}>DAYS</span></Col>
          <Col style={styleCol} className={style.clockFrame} lg={3} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>{hours} <span style={styleColSpan}>HOURS</span></Col>
          <Col style={styleCol} className={style.clockFrame} lg={3} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>{minutes} <span style={styleColSpan}>MINS</span></Col>
          <Col style={styleCol} className={style.clockFrame} lg={3} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>{seconds} <span style={styleColSpan}>SEC</span></Col>
        </>
      );
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <Container fluid style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(186, 205, 214, 1)'}} className={style.mainFrame}>
        <Row style={{margin:'auto', paddingTop:'40px',
           justifyContent:'center'}} className={style.clockFrame}>
           {renderer}
 
          <Countdown date={Date.now() + 100000} renderer={renderer} />
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
  }
}
export default Home
```

in chrome and firefox browsers, the function works.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFI40.png)

but in safari return NaN.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1StZ.jpg)

anyone can help me please ?

Comment: {renderer() } instead of {renderer}. And also paass them suitable arguments